# why does secret management tool SecretHub work locally but not in heroku production?

Tags: node.js, heroku, secret-key, app-secret

I decided to implement a secret management service ([secrethub.io](https://secrethub.io)) for a node.js server hosted by Heroku.

Its install process goes something like:

```
npm install --save-dev @secrethub/cli
secrethub init
```

(then a credential is given once you signup)

then you adjust main start script to:

```
secrethub run -- nodemon server.js
```

now when i run the app locally with `npm run start` everything is fine, server runs as it should, secrets are injected, all is good. but when i deploy to Heroku, the app crashes immediately on the start script:

> server@1.0.0 start /app 2020-09-28T22:42:08.353088+00:00
> app[web.1]: > secrethub run -- nodemon server.js
> 2020-09-28T22:42:08.353088+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2020-09-28T22:42:08.469775+00:00 app[web.1]: Encountered an error:
> error while processing template file 'secrethub.env': could not find
> credential file. Go to https://signup.secrethub.io/ to create an
> account or run `secrethub init` to use an already existing account on
> this machine. (secrethub.credential_not_exist)
> (run.template_parsing_failed)  2020-09-28T22:42:08.484159+00:00
> app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 2020-09-28T22:42:08.484663+00:00
> app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1 2020-09-28T22:42:08.493367+00:00
> app[web.1]: npm ERR! aflare-stripe@1.0.0 start: `secrethub run -- nodemon server.js` 2020-09-28T22:42:08.493885+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
> ERR! Exit status 1 2020-09-28T22:42:08.494399+00:00 app[web.1]: npm
> ERR!  2020-09-28T22:42:08.494840+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at
> the aflare-stripe@1.0.0 start script. 2020-09-28T22:42:08.495292+00:00
> app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
> likely additional logging output above.
> 2020-09-28T22:42:08.515466+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2020-09-28T22:42:08.516772+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log
> of this run can be found in: 2020-09-28T22:42:08.517179+00:00
> app[web.1]: npm ERR!
> /app/.npm/_logs/2020-09-28T22_42_08_498Z-debug.log

like i said I've already signed up and everything. Anyone know of any issues deploying to Heroku and using secret management services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the following part of the log, it looks like the SecretHub CLI does not have access to a credential:

> could not find credential file. Go to https://signup.secrethub.io/ to create an account or run secrethub init to use an already existing account on this machine. (secrethub.credential_not_exist)

You can solve this, by creating a service account for your Heroku app. You can follow [this guide](https://secrethub.io/docs/start/deploy/other/#service) to see how. You can configure the resulting credential as the `SECRETHUB_CREDENTIAL` environment variable in Heroku (see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) how).